# Do you have to increment ostream_iterator when writing?

Tags: c++

In many examples of `ostream_iterator` I notice that an increment operation is used between writes:

e.g.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  ostream_iterator<char> itr{ cout };
  *itr = 'H';
  ++itr; // commenting out this line appears to yield the same output
  *itr = 'i';
}
```

On the [cpp reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/ostream_iterator) increment (`operator++`) is listed as a no-op. Is there a reason to include it despite being a no-op? Is it a "best-practice" to include?

Comment: It's probably just there for generic code. If you have the iterator as a template parameter, you might not know what type it is. So they all support incrementing for consistency.

Comment: If you follow the link https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/ostream_iterator/operator_arith it explains why (for generic code)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why does `ostream_iterator` exist at all, when you can print directly to `cout`?

Answer: to be used with functions that expect an iterator.

There is a bunch of requirements that a type has to satisfy to be "an iterator" (and that those functions expect), and overloading `++` and `*` in a certain way is one of them.

Both `*` and `++` do nothing for an ostream iterator. If you're asking if you should call them or not, you don't need `ostream_iterator` in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

Consider a possible implementation of [`std::copy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy):

> ```
> template<class InputIt, class OutputIt>
> OutputIt copy(InputIt first, InputIt last, 
>               OutputIt d_first)
> {
>     for (; first != last; (void)++first, (void)++d_first) {
>         *d_first = *first;
>     }
>     return d_first;
> }
> ```

This code works with all output iterators. It also works with `std::ostream_iterator`. `++d_first` is a noop in this case, but it still it has to be valid code, because for other output iterators it is needed.

Actually the major reason for `std::ostream_iterator` to exists is to be used with such generic algorithms, otherwise you could just write to the stream directly. Its a nice example of iterators being the glue between algorithms and container or more generally the data. Algorithms can be generic and need not care where the data is actually coming from or going to, because the iterator implements the special case.

Also from [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/ostream_iterator/operator_arith) on `std::ostream_iterator::operator++`:

> Does nothing. These operator overloads are provided to satisfy the
> requirements of LegacyOutputIterator. They make it possible for the
> expressions `*iter++=value` and `*++iter=value` to be used to output
> (insert) a value into the underlying stream.

For your actual question:

> Is there a reason to include it despite being a no-op? Is it a "best-practice" to include?

No. There is no point in incrementing the iterator when you know its a `std::ostream_iterator`. The only reason it can be incremented (which is a noop) is for generic code.